# Windows service does not start after machine reboots unless a user signs in

Tags: windows-server, windows-services, windows-server-2019

I have a Windows Server 2019 remote server machine and I have been trying to deploy a windows service. Everything works fine except that when I restart my machine, the service does not start unless I sign in as a user. I'd like the service to start as soon as the machine restarts (without a user signing in) and I was wondering if there is a way to go about this. After I restart the machine, signing in and out of it does not affect the service

Comment: In service properties, what are the settings in the tabs "Log On" and "Dependencies"?

Comment: Are you using your user account as the service account or an internal service account?